# In elastic search, using the REST API and update by query, I need the search to wait for the completion before showing results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index in Elastic Search (v7.15) that I'm updating by using the REST API and `update_by_query?wait_for_completion`.

While doing this update I might get some search hits in the index from other processes, I want them to wait for the completion of the update before returning any result.

I can see that `?refresh?wait_for` can be used for this, but not with `_update_by_query`, is there an alternative?

As per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/docs-update-by-query.html#:%7E:text=Refreshing%20shards,support%20wait_for.) for `refresh`:

> Refreshing shards
> Specifying the refresh parameter refreshes all shards once the request completes. This is different than the update API’s refresh parameter, which causes just the shard that received the request to be refreshed. Unlike the update API, it does not support wait_for.

What will happen if the `_update_by_query` is not completed and a search is performed?

Comment: You will see the latest version of the document available for searching. Which value in refresh_interval?

Comment: @rabbitbr, my scenario is that I'm updating a number of documents and another user might do a search, I don't want the search of the user to complete and see stale documents, I prefer that the search in the user waits for the update to complete.

Comment: I don't have a refresh_interval value in my `_settings`, I understand that will be the default 1s